# How to get away with error "no lines available in input"?

Tags: r, pdf, tabulizer

I am converting pdf to data frame using `extract_table` function of tabulizer package but keeps on getting error of no lines available. I ran the code on 3 pdf files. I ran perfectly for first pdf but gave error on remaining 2 files.

```
agri_table <- extract_tables("kp_2018-19.pdf",
                             output = "data.frame",
                             pages = c(1), 
                             area = list(
                               c(172.1,77.5,693,536)
                             ),
                             guess = FALSE
                             
)
```

The error occur in first line of code. Please help.

Comment: Is there anything on the first page of that document? The error seems to suggest there isn't.

Comment: Yes. All pages of the document have tables

Comment: Difficult to help further without a reproducible example. I would just point that your code indicates to only take the first page.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: problem have been solved. I was trying to get table from the print document but when I loaded the original document and extracted table from there the code worked fine.